# Get ListView Item display percentage

Tags: android, listview, scroll, row-height

I'm writing an application where I need to get how much a particular item of Listview is displaying. This way:

[image]

So while scrolling here top view item display only 40% size of it's size, center one displaying completely and lower one displaying only 20% of it's size. Any suggestion here !

Comment: How are you calculating the percentages??

Comment: That is what my problem...I'm not sure how to do that...the display percentage of List view item. Say it's actual size is 200dp then how much it's displaying.